# Long random string generator in PHP

Tags: php, random

Does anyone know how to generate a long (e.g. 280 characters) random `string` in PHP without having to use a `for` loop that will loop through characters 280 times? I need it in order to create a custom session ID.

The PHPSESSID is not secure enough in my opinion being too short and not too random. I know Facebook and Twitter, use long session IDs (150, 550 chars respectively).

There could be an option to use `MD5` strings or `Bcrypt` encryption of different string such as `PHPSESSID`, host, User-Agent etc. but I'm not sure this is the right way of doing it.

Comment: Why without using a for loop? Just use an array of characters and refer to them in the loop as `for ($i = 0; $i < 280; $i++) $buffer .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength)];`

Comment: What's wrong with looping? And if you want to reduce the number of loops, you can always concat several hashes.

Comment: Nothing wrong with loops, it just uses some memory, on a website with higher traffic, this could probably slow down the loading time a bit.

Comment: If you don't want to use a for loop, you could always use a while loop instead

Comment: I don't want to be overly blunt here, but if your site gets slowed down by a trivial for loop iterating 280 times, you've got *serious* problems. On most modern hardware, we're talking literally 100 microseconds... [A Quick Benchmark](http://3v4l.org/TvbrE)....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're asking a question like that, it probably means you don't know anything about cryptography or security. Trying to generate a "long random string" because, as you say, "The PHPSESSID is not secure enough" will probably lead you to a custom and insecure implementation.

Generating a random string is **IMPOSSIBLE**, at least not with your current hardware: you may approximate a fair pseudorandom generator but that is only useful for educational purposes.

PHP's Session ID generation algorithm is fairly efficient; if you think it is not secure enough, then you'll likely waste time making it better. You may probably want to use a different authentication mechanism if you are looking at maximum security (using a client certificate for example).

If websites such as Twitter, Facebook, or another site with similar traffic use longer session IDs, it may be not because it is more secure (well in a way), but rather because it avoids conflicts.

Finally, if you want a longer session ID without trying to write your own algorithm, you should use the following PHP configuration directive:

[`session.hash_function`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.hash-function) which can take any hash algorithm known by PHP.

You may also want to use [`session.bits_per_characters`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.hash-bits-per-character) to shorten or lengthen the string. Note that if you do this, the string may be longer or shorter, but the data remains the same -- only represented differently (base 16, base 32, etc.)

Additional info:

You may also increase the entropy by using a custom source (file) and setting the length of the seed:

```
ini_set("session.hash_function", "sha512");
ini_set("session.bits_per_charater", 4); // 4 means hex
ini_set("session.entropy_file", "/dev/urandom");
ini_set("session.entropy_length", "512");
```

Comment: "The PHPSESSID is not secure enough" has nothing to do with my skills and for sure you're not the person to judge it. The PHPSESSID weaknesses is not something I discovered but highly discussed over the web, but anyway I thank you for taking your time to share your ideas and experience with us.

Comment: I don't "judge" your global skills, I just made an assumption based on your question. Don't be offended. That's being said I removed the "skills" part, but it still applies.

Comment: I was not offended by what you said because I do agree I haven't use `cryptography` before and the application I'm working on requires a bit of extra security.So, that's why I posted this question to see what others say about that and what's the most common way to go, I could use a `loop` to generate a string and concatenate it with an `md5` of the user `User-Agent` but wasn't sure it's right.

Comment: @AndreiStalbe: This answer and the answer PaulDixon provided just make it plain obvious that the built-in PHP session generator is pretty good. The chances of session hijacking are quite low and you could make them even lower by feeding some better / larger random data.

Comment: Thank you for your answers guys, it really helped me to decide which way to go.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The best advice is the line about setting the `session.entropy_file` to `/dev/urandom`. That's the only thing that increases the actual entropy to acceptable levels. The problem that @AndreiStalbe is indicating occurs when you leave that blank, and php effectively uses `rand()`. But no, you don't need to do anything fancy. And in general, never use Facebook or Twitter as examples of what you should do, they have problems (and experts to solve them) that most devs would only dream of. A cursory "but they do x" doesn't help much...

Answer (score 5):

Can it be <strike>binary</strike> hexadecimal?

```
bin2hex(mcrypt_create_iv(140, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM));
```

Or if you have access to [`hash_pbkdf2()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-pbkdf2.php):

```
hash_pbkdf2('sha256', PHPSESSID, mt_rand(), 1, 280, false);
```

Comment: This might work for him `bin2hex(mcrypt_create_iv(140, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM))`

Comment: Hash functions like `bcrypt` or `PBKDF2` are designed to use a lot of time, what is good for hashing passwords, because you would need a lot of time to find out the original password. For generating a random string it's absolutely the wrong tool, the resulting id will be in no way more unique or unpredictable. The first way with `mcrypt_create_iv()` is appropriate for this job.

Comment: @martinstoeckli: PBKDF2 consumes time by stretching the key (2048 times in my example). You could set that to a really low value if you needed to.

Comment: @Alix Axel - If you do not want to make iterations and set the iterations to 1, you can directly call `sha256`. It's like writing a for loop, when you know that it only runs once. And iterating will in no way improve the result, it only makes your server busy.

Comment: @martinstoeckli: It's not like that. **1.** Calling `sha256` directly will never yield a 280 byte string, while PBKDF2 will. **2.** Iterating will actually improve the result (in terms of security) - not that I think it's relevant to the OP objective, and that's why I changed it.

Comment: @martinstoeckli: See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php#109260 for a implementation of the PBKDF2 algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

You'll probably find that not all the bits in a "long" session id are purely random - they might provide additional information to the application to enable rapid extraction of key information.

PHP session ids by default aren't too bad, and can be improved by providing some extra entropy (e.g. from /dev/urandom)

Look at php_session_create_id in [ext/session/session.c](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/session/session.c#L279) in the php source

It goes like this:

- get time of day
- get remote ip address
- build a string with the seconds and microseconds from the current time, along with the IP address
- feed that into configured [session hash function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.hash-function) (either MD5 or SHA1)
- if configured, feed some additional randomness from an [entropy file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.entropy-file)
- generate final hash value

So getting a duplicate or predicting a session id is pretty difficult.

Comment: Sorry I can't have 2 correct answers to check yours as well. But thank you for your explanation. +1.

Answer (score -2):

Make yourself a long string and [shuffle](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) it.

```
$string = 'asdfhdfiadfshsdfDSGFADSFDSFDSFER524353452345';
$new_string = shuffle($string);
```

Comment: -1 Shuffle uses rand() which obviously isn't random enough for OP based on what he/she asked. Also, this doesn't create a random string, this places certain string in "random" order.